# Access control lists in Symfony2 using FOSUserBundle - adding roles to a user

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, acl, fosuserbundle

I'm hoping this is more simple than the docs I've been reading.

I have a number of entities with ManyToOne relationships with a standard FOSUserbundle user entity that can login users, register them, logout etc.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Each of my users can also have a number of pets. I.e. here's the cat entity (simplified):

```
class Cat
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $user_id;
```

How should I add an access control list user role that defines if the user has any cats or not, and if they do, allows them onto the "cats only" part of my website.

Note (slightly related): I feel mildly retarded when it comes to database design using doctrine, I'll upvote anyone that can point me to a good tutorial / explanation of designing things with different kind of joins, especially if it's a in Symfony/Doctrine environment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you haven't gotten anything else yet. I'll throw something out there but my experience is only moderate so far.

In the controller for your cats owners page, you could query if the user has any associated cat entities.

You need to add OneToMany/ManyToOne annotations to your user and cat class, and a variable for the associations. This you could review straight out of the doctrine section of the symfony2 book (If you are working with Symfony2 and haven't taken the time to read the book, that is the minimal level of knowledge to work with the full stack and I suggest you read it all). (Do you really need a entity class just for cat, you could have a pet entity with a "type" option.)

check the security context to ensure logged in, then query db.

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $ownersCats = $em->getRepository('PetsPetSiteBundle:Blog')->findBy(array('type'=>'cat'));
```

or for one result only

```
    $ownersCats = $em->getRepository('PetsPetSiteBundle:Blog')->findOneBy(array('type'=>'cat'));
```

Once you have this result if it comes back false, you know he has no cats. Otherwise continue.

Obviously you could make this perform better by only querying for id's or something if you don't plan on using the entities on that page or just performing a count query and seeing if it's greater than 0?